# SDL_DisplayFormat works, but not SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha

Tags: c++, sdl

The following code is intended to display a green square on a black background.  It executes, but the green square does not show up.  However, if I change `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha` to `SDL_DisplayFormat` the square is rendered correctly.

So what don't I understand?  It seems to me that I am creating `*surface` with an alpha mask and I am using `SDL_MapRGBA` to map my green color, so it would be consistent to use `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha` as well.

(I removed error-checking for clarity, but none of the SDL API calls fail in this example.)

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(
        640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF
    );

    SDL_Surface *temp = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(
        SDL_HWSURFACE, 100, 100, 32, 0, 0, 0,
        ( SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN ? 0x000000ff : 0xff000000 )
    );

    SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha( temp );

    SDL_FreeSurface( temp );

    SDL_FillRect(
        surface, &surface->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGBA(
            screen->format, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff
        )
    );

    SDL_Rect r;
    r.x = 50;
    r.y = 50;

    SDL_BlitSurface( surface, NULL, screen, &r );

    SDL_Flip( screen );

    SDL_Delay( 1000 );

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong format for SDL_MapRGBA.  Should have been

```
SDL_FillRect(
    surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGBA(
        surface->format, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff
    )
);
```

(`surface->format` instead of `screen->format`.)  I thought the two would be equivalent.  And they are after calling `SDL_DisplayFormat()`, but *not* after calling `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha()`.  The screen surface doesn't have an alpha channel, so the format is different between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if this is the issue, but the masks in your `SDL_CreateRGBSurface()` call look wrong. Perhaps try what [the SDL wiki](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_CreateRGBSurface) says:

```
const SDL_PixelFormat& format = *screen->format;

SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(
  SDL_HWSURFACE,
  width,
  height,
  32,
  format.Rmask,
  format.Gmask,
  format.Bmask,
  format.Amask
);
```

Perhaps the upper bits (where the red channel ought to be) are being interpreted as the alpha channel; since they’re zero, the resulting surface would be fully transparent.

Comment: The `SDL_PixelFormat` structure provides `Rmask`, `Gmask`, `Bmask` and `Amask` members. I can't tell for sure, but they are probably cross-platform`, so you can skip this pre-processor condition and use `screen->format->[A,G,B,A]mask`.

Comment: @Asakeron: You’re right. I had forgotten about that. Been a while since I’ve used SDL actively.

Comment: Also, I don't think endianness is the problem, because Bounderby is already checking that.

Comment: I tried this.  Makes no difference.  I also tried using white (0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff) which also made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the pixel colors in your surface before calling `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha`, it might work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(
        640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF
    );

    SDL_Surface *temp = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(
    SDL_HWSURFACE, 100, 100, 32, screen->format.Rmask, screen->format.Amask, screen->format.Bmask, screen->format.Amask);

Uint32 *pixels  =(Uint32*) temp->pixels;

for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
{
    pixels[i] = SDL_MapRGBA(screen->format, 0, 255, 0, 255);
}


SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha( temp );

    SDL_Rect r;
    r.x = 50;
    r.y = 50;

    SDL_BlitSurface( surface, NULL, screen, &r );

    SDL_Flip( screen );

    SDL_Delay( 1000 );

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I also removed your endianness check. I'm using the masks provided by the [`SDL_PixelFormat`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_PixelFormat) structure. See my [comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41954/sdl-displayformat-works-but-not-sdl-displayformatalpha#comment69816_41957) to Jon Purdy's answer for more information.

Comment: Hmm.  This is strange.  I tried filling the surface before calling SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha.  Now the surface renders, but it still doesn't seem to use the alpha channel.  I tested by trying to blend two surfaces.